# UK Visa while on short-term Schengen Visa

Tags: schengen, uk

I am an Indian citizen visiting Germany for tourism on short-term (3 months)Schengen Visa. While in Germany, can I apply for a UK Tourism Visa in Germany (Munich/Duesseldorf)? I appreciate your answers.

Answer (score 0):

You can apply, but it may be unwise to do so:

- You might not have all the documents you need with you.
- It might take longer to process your application than your remaining time in the Schengen area.
- The UKVI might be unable to verify your documents, leading to a visa refusal.

If your situation is especially strong, e.g. you are a high net worth individual with strong ties to your home country, then you almost certainly can get a visa. But most people would be well advised to make the application in their home countries.